# maven gives compilation error before loading dependencies

Tags: java, maven, compilation

I am trying to build a project using 'mvn clean install' This gives me compilation error for some packages missing. When I look into the m2 folder, the local repository is not created. 
How do I enforce the loading of dependencies before the compilation of the projec?

Some of the things I tried
mvn clean install -U
Delete the .project, .classpath, .settings

Any options?

Comment: please, show maven error

Comment: Is this an existing project, or a brand new one? I would suggest that you generate the project from a maven archetype, and it will always compile and build out of the box. For example, see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html and try the maven-archetype-quickstart.

Comment: This is an existing project

Comment: Dependencies are downloaded during the compile phase. Providing the error as well as the pom.xml would help in figuring out the issue.